# Use XSLT to create a tag that has the name of a attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am transforming a xml file into a html with xforms one and I want to insert a new tag inside the xforms model with the name of a attribute (extracted with XPath).

Basically I have this XML:

```
<structure>
   <part class='Button' id="b0"/>            
   <part class="Button" id="b1"/> 
   <part class="TextBox" id="t1"/>
</structure>
```

And I want to create just empty tags for the xforms model as instance elements. So I need to declare the `part` that has a class `TextBox` by adding a new empty tag with the name of the `id` attribute - so `<t1/>`. 
I need this as a XForms instance element. 
I have written the following XSLT, but I am not sure if I am in the right direction (trying with escape `&gt;` and `&lt;`)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <xf:model id="model{position()}">
                <xf:instance id="formData{position()}">                        
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="part[@class='TextBox']">
                            <xsl:for-each select="part[@class='TextBox']">
                                <xsl:element name="textBox">
                                    &gt;
                                    <xsl:value-of select="{@id}"/>
                                    &lt;
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>                                
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xf:instance>
            </xf:model>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Perhaps, it's trivial, but I can't get my head around it.. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
The final result should be:

```
.....
<head>
   <xf:model>
      <xf:instance>
         <data xmlns="">
            <t1/>
         </data>
      </xf:instance>
   </xf:model>
</head>
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the `<t1>` element you can use `<xsl:element>`:

```
 <xsl:element name="{@id}"/>
```

You probably won't be able to generate `<data xmlns="">` unless you have a default namespace defined in some ancestor element (for example: `<html xmlns="html-namespace">`). Then you can write it directly to the result tree:

```
<data xmlns="">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}"/>
</data>
```

Your template creates a context in `/`, which does not have a `<part>` child. Either you place everything in a template that matches `structure`, or you add `structure` as a parent selector   in the expressions that contain `part`:

```
<xsl:when test="structure/part[@class='TextBox']">
    <xsl:for-each select="structure/part[@class='TextBox']"> ...
```

That should allow you to generate the result you expect.

Comment: Yes ... that's it - when I added the whole path in the template I got what I wanted. Thanks for the valuable input! :)